# Ошибка PyInstaller. (Python 3.5.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, pyinstaller

Я пытаюсь преобразовать довольно простую игру Python в исполняемый файл и у меня ничего не получилось. Вот ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\Кирил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xea' in file C:\Users\Кирил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

А вот код игры:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    import colorama, logging, os
    logging.basicConfig(filename = "game.log", level = logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s[LINE:%(lineno)d] - %(message)s', datefmt = '%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')
    colorama.init()

    red = '\x1b[6;30;41m'
    green = '\x1b[6;30;42m'
    n_text = '\x1b[4;31;47m'
    end = '\x1b[0m'

    class Player:
        data = {'health': '100', 'money': '100', 'name': 'player', 'chapter': '1'}
        inv = {}

        #saving function
        def save_game(self):
            f = open('savefile.txt', 'w') #open file

            f.write(p.data.get('health')) #writing
            f.write(" ")
            f.write(p.data.get('money'))
            f.write(" ")
            f.write(p.data.get('name'))
            f.write(" ")
            f.write(p.data.get('chapter'))

            f.close() #closing

        #loading function
        def load_game(self):
            f = open('savefile.txt', 'r') #open file

            save = f.readline() #reading first string
            save = save.split() #spliting up first string

            f.close() #closing

            return save #list output

        def init_var(self): #needed before saving
            p.data = {'health': list[0], 'money': list[1], 'name': list[2], 'chapter': str(list[3])}

        def clear_log(self):
            logfile_size = os.stat('game.log').st_size // 1024

            if logfile_size >= 10:
                f = open('game.log', 'r+')
                f.truncate()
                logging.info('Log file is cleaned.')
                f.close()

            if logfile_size < 10:
                logging.info('Сleaning the log file is not required.')

    p = Player()

    list = p.load_game()
    logging.info('Save: {}'.format(list))

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

    print('                               __   ')
    print('  ________ __   ____   _______/  |_ ')
    print(' / ____/  |  \_/ __ \ /  ___/\   __\ ')
    print('< <_|  |  |  /\  ___/ \___ \  |  |  ')
    print(' \__   |____/  \___  >____  > |__| ')
    print('    |__|           \/     \/        \n')

    if list[3] == '1': #chapter one
        print(n_text + '--------------------------------------Chapter one: name---------------------------------------------' + end)
        print(n_text + 'chapter one' + end)
        input('Нажмите Enter...')

        list[3] = str(int(p.data.get('chapter')) + 1)
        a = 'You have reached chapter ' + list[3] + '!'
        logging.info(a)
        p.init_var()
        p.save_game()
        os.system('cls')

    if list[3] == '2': #chapter two
        print(n_text + '--------------------------------------Chapter two: name---------------------------------------------' + end)
        print(n_text + 'chapter two' + end)
        input('Нажмите Enter...')

        list[3] = str(int(list[3]) + 1)
        a = 'You have reached chapter ' + list[3] + '!'
        logging.info(a)
        p.init_var()
        p.save_game()
        os.system('cls')

    if list[3] == '3': #chapter three
        print(n_text + '--------------------------------------Chapter three: name-------------------------------------------' + end)
        print(n_text + 'chapter three' + end)
        input('Нажмите Enter...')

        list[3] = str(int(list[3]) + 1)
        a = 'You have reached chapter ' + list[3] + '!'
        logging.info(a)
        p.init_var()
        p.save_game()
        os.system('cls')

    if list[3] == '4': #chapter four
        print(n_text + '--------------------------------------Chapter four: name--------------------------------------------' + end)
        print(n_text + 'chapter four' + end)
        input('Нажмите Enter...')

        list[3] = str(int(list[3]) + 1)
        a = 'You have reached chapter ' + list[3] + '!'
        logging.info(a)
        p.init_var()
        p.save_game()
        os.system('cls')

    if list[3] == '5': #chapter five
        print(n_text + '--------------------------------------Chapter five: name--------------------------------------------' + end)
        print(n_text + 'chapter five' + end)
        input('Нажмите Enter...')

        list[3] = str(int(list[3]) + 1)
        a = 'You have reached chapter ' + list[3] + '!'
        logging.info(a)
        p.init_var()
        p.save_game()
        p.clear_log()
        os.system('cls')

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

    p.init_var()
    p.save_game()
    logging.info('Data that has been saved: {}'.format(p.data))

except ImportError:
    print('Error importing libraries for the game. Wait for updates.')
    logging.critical('Error importing libraries for the game.')

except OSError:
    print('OS error. Wait for updates.')
    logging.critical('OS error.')

except SyntaxError:
    print('Syntax error. Wait for updates.')
    logging.critical('Syntax error.')

except SystemError:
    print('Internal error. Wait for updates.')
    logging.critical('Internal error.')

except:
    print('Unspecified error. Wait for updates.')
    logging.critical('Unspecified error.')
```

Может знает кто как решить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Проверьте кодировку самого файла скрипта.

Comment: Проверил. UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразуйте файл в кодировку UTF-8. Например с помощью Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Я это уже сделал, но в notepad++. Ничего не помогло. Но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Retell На всякий случай предложу такой способ. Создайте пустой документ в кодировке UTF-8, затем скопируйте код из файла, вставьте и сохраните.

Answer (score 0):

*File "C:\Users\Кирил\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py"*

**Кирил**

Совет если вплотную собираетесь заниматься Python поменяйте на Kiril

Comment: Попробовал у себя собралось аж бегом Windows 8.1 Python 3.6.0 Pyinstaller 3.3.1

Comment: Или сделайте экранирование пути

Comment: вот так--> r"Путь к файлу"